# Facebook integration with IBM websphere

Tags: java, websphere-commerce

I am trying to integrate my websphere commerce application with Facebook login.

I tried the steps mentioned at IBM Websphere commerce Knowledge Center

Step 1: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.starterstores.doc/tasks/tsmfbintegrationstorefunction.htm

Step 2:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.starterstores.doc/tasks/tsmfbint_facebkauth.htm

Step 3: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.starterstores.doc/tasks/tsm_fbintconfigfbappID.htm

Step 4: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.starterstores.doc/tasks/tsmtestingfbint.htm

but "Connect to Facebook" button hasn't appeared on the home page(or anywhere as a matter of fact) on my website.

what did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution!!!!

Have to include

Madisons\include\styles\style1\CachedHeaderDisplayFacebook.jspf

in your page(home, cataloge, catagery).

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.starterstores.doc/refs/rsmsocfbinthomepage.htm